# socket.io official client connection issues?

Tags: ios, node.js, ios8, websocket, socket.io

I am working with iOS 8 and Swift. I want to use the official socket.io client but for some reason it does not attempt to connect. I followed the example given here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

```swift
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "\(CurrentConfiguration.serverURL)") 

socket.reconnects = true
socket.reconnectWait = 10
socket.nsp = "/messagelist"

// Connect
socket.connect()

socket.onAny {println("got event: \($0.event) with items \($0.items)")} 
socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
    println("socket connected")
}

socket.on("error") {data in
    println("socket ERROR")
    println(data)
}
```

Can anyone confirm this? Is this a version problem or maybe related to Swift 1.2?

On the server side i cant even recognize a connection attempt. The variable serverURL is the same as i had before and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to call `socket.connect()` after you call your handlers. A good practice would be to create a function with all of your required handlers, and call it in the `viewDidLoad` method. Aftewards you would then call the connect method.

Example:

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "URL") 

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   // socket.io
   addHandlers()
   socket.connect()
}

func addHandlers() {

   self.socket.onAny {println("Got event: \($0.event), with items: \($0.items)")}

   self.socket.on("processReq") {[weak self] data, ack in
   // handler code here
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @rambossa your tip for calling connect after adding handler saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use SocketIOClient instance as class property.

```
class aClass {
    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: url)

    func someFunction() {
        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            println("socket connected")
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's because there's lots of closures used in it.

Comment: well ok, i can do a new class and make everything a class method but how do i connect in the VC anyway? I tried your solution but it still wont even try to connect